# Snapshot Root Exists but is not writable

Tags: cron, rsnapshot

I have rsnapshot configured to take daily alpha snapshots.
The command for the snapshot is configured in `/etc/cron.d/rsnapshot`, with the specific user as "root".
The permissions of the rsnapshot_root directory are `drwxr-x--- root sudo`.

I used the rsnapshot configtest command and it reported "Syntax OK".

I have checked in on the snapshots, and they appear to be working. This morning's alpha snapshot shows changes in files that I made yesterday, so it appears to have successfully taken this morning's snapshot.

However, I got this error sent to my s-nail inbox this morning:

```
rsnapshot encountered an error! The program was invoked with these options:
/usr/bin/rsnapshot alpha
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
ERROR: /etc/rsnapshot.conf on line 23:
ERROR: snapshot_root /var/cache/rsnapshot/ - snapshot_root exists but is \
         not writable
ERROR: /etc/rsnapshot.conf on line 227:
ERROR: backup /home/ localhost/ - snapshot_root needs to be defined before \
         backup points
ERROR: /etc/rsnapshot.conf on line 228:
ERROR: backup /etc/ localhost/ - snapshot_root needs to be defined before \
         backup points
ERROR: /etc/rsnapshot.conf on line 229:
ERROR: backup /usr/local/ localhost/ - snapshot_root needs to be defined \
         before backup points
ERROR: /etc/rsnapshot.conf on line 230:
ERROR: backup /var/www/ localhost/ - snapshot_root needs to be defined \
         before backup points
ERROR: ---------------------------------------------------------------------
ERROR: Errors were found in /etc/rsnapshot.conf,
ERROR: rsnapshot can not continue. If you think an entry looks right, make
ERROR: sure you don't have spaces where only tabs should be.
```

Since the snapshot from this morning looks accurate, can I ignore this warning? Can I silence the warning? What is causing this warning?
Thank you.

EDIT:
Manually running rsnapshot runs successfully.

```
notsysadmin@redacted:/etc$ sudo /usr/bin/rsnapshot alpha
[sudo] password for notsysadmin:
notsysadmin@redacted:/etc$ grep rsnapshot /var/log/syslog
Apr 21 03:00:02 redacted CRON[187802]: (root) CMD (/usr/bin/rsnapshot alpha)
Apr 21 03:00:02 redacted rsnapshot[187803]: /usr/bin/rsnapshot alpha: completed successfully
Apr 21 10:56:08 redacted rsnapshot[190709]: /usr/bin/rsnapshot alpha: completed successfully
```

I did look over the config file. It is huge, unfortunately, so it is possible I missed something.
I used nano to make edits. I don't know if nano does silent replac, but when I use arrowkeys on the line, the tab remains (has not been replaced by spaces).
Moreover, the fact I can run the snapshot manually makes me think it is okay.

I haven't gotten anymore alerts, actually, so it may be that the file USED to be misconfigured but the mail couldn't deliver until yesterday because I didn't have my mail server set up correctly.

Comment: Before suggesting you should ignore these errors, have you tried running `rsnapshot` at the command line?  i.e., just `sudo /usr/bin/rsnapshot alpha`?  And have you followed its advice and checked to make sure you haven't mixed up spaces and tabs?  `rsnapshot` is rather picky about that in its configuration file...  For example, are you sure you aren't using an editor that is silently replacing one with the other?

Comment: I am adding to the post the answers to your questions.

Comment: Given that the command runs, I'm more inclined to believe that the issue was with the `cronjob` itself.  Perhaps the first error arises because you ran the command as a non-root user.  And all subsequent errors are due to this first one failing.  This is perhaps a bit of stretch, but it's the only explanation I can think of.  Indeed, it seems your `/etc/rsnapshot.conf` must be well-formed or else it wouldn't execute.  I suppose you can see if this problem occurs again?

Comment: As for the tab character, I tend to avoid `nano` as it seems to not insert tabs correctly.  I usually choose `emacs` over `nano` if I need to insert tab characters.  Others might give you a better solution, but my silly way to find tab characters is to `cat -n file.txt | less` to find the line.  Then `head -n X file.txt | tail -n 1` to extract just that line.  And pipe this to `od -t uC`.  You'll get the ASCII code of each character in that line.  From here, you want to see 9 (tab) instead of 32 (space character).  A very low tech way, I guess...

Comment: ugh I hope I don't find myself having to search for tabs... but thank you, I will inevitably need to..

Comment: It might be easier to download the original `rsnapshot` `.deb` file, and pull the `rsnapshot.conf` file out.  And then modify it using the differences between it and your file.  That might be easier than checking every line in your file...

Answer (score 0):

You need the run the cron job as root.

Comment: Literally the second line of my post 
> "The command for the snapshot is configured in /etc/cron.d/rsnapshot, with the specific user as "root". "
Thank you.